# Error al Mostrar PDF - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

He actualizado mi pregunta, bueno en estos momentos tengo un pequeño aplicativo y al momento de ejecutarlo puedo crear y mostrar pdf, pero tengo un problema y es que el pdf se crea correctamente pero al momento de que el aplicativo lo muestra, sale todo negro pdf...me podrian ayudar?

-Codigo:

```
static String envio="";
public void crearYmostrarPDF() {
    Document documento = new Document();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd HH:mm:ss");
    String DateTimeActual = sdf2.format(c.getTime());

    try {
        File file = crearFichero(NOMBRE_DOCUMENTO+"_"+DateTimeActual+"_Cita.pdf");
        FileOutputStream ficheroPDF = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        //
        envio=NOMBRE_DOCUMENTO+"_"+DateTimeActual+"_Cita.pdf";
        //
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, ficheroPDF);

        documento.open();

        documento.add(new Paragraph("TABLA \n\n"));
        documento.add(new Paragraph( etTexto.getText().toString()+"\n\n"));

        // Insertamos una tabla
        PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(5);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++) {
            tabla.addCell("CELDA "+i);
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+envio, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        documento.add(tabla);
    } catch(DocumentException e) {
    } catch(IOException e) {
    } finally {
        documento.close();

        File file = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MisPDFs/" + envio);
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+envio, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
        Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        target.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

        Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Abrir PDF");
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // el usuario no tiene ninguna app que pueda abrir pdfs
        }
    }
}
```

Foto del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya intestaste abrir el archivo directamente desde la carpeta en la cual se descargo ?, e intenta agregar  algun error que te muestre el Logcat.

Comment: @A.Palacio lo he puesto diractamente y sigue saliendo todo negro, en el logcat no me sale nada :s

Answer (score 0):

crea un AsyncTask  donde pongas tu código de creación de pdf. y en el post .. abrir dicho archivo.

tomo esto como referencia.

```
        private void crearMostrarPDF() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(actBuscarEquipo.this, "Por favor espere", "Creando",
                    true);


            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>() {



                @Override
                protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    crearPDF();
                    return 1;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if (res == 0) {
                        FunctionsUtil.ShowMessage("No se pudo generar PDF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                    } else {

                        FunctionsUtil.ShowMessage("Se creo PDF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    // TU METODO DE ABRIR PDF



   File fichero = new File(valoresGenerales.EXT_STORAGE_DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTOS + nombre_completo);
            if (fichero.exists()) {
                File file = new File(valoresGenerales.EXT_STORAGE_DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTOS + nombre_completo);
                MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getName());
                String type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext.toLowerCase());

                if (type == null)
                    type = "*/*";

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri data = Uri.fromFile(file);

                intent.setDataAndType(data, type);

                startActivity(intent);
            }



                    }

                }

            }.execute();

        }
```

Comment: lo que yo quisiera saber es como mostrarlo, ya que eso es lo que no se :s

Comment: acabo de actualizar... ese metodo busca cualquier archivo en la ubicación EXT_STORAGE_DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTOS  (variable mía  ) + nombre del archivo.   abre cualquier tipo de archivo siempre y cuando el equipo android cuente con la app que lo pueda abrir.